# R - Handling shapefiles in the spatstat package ISSUES converting spatiallinesdataframe to psp

Tags: r, shapefile, spatstat

My ultimate goal is to use the Spatstat pointsOnLines function to create points along a set of route lines which I have coerced from a SpatialLinesDataFrame to a psp object.

I am starting with a shape file that I have loaded with rgdal OGR.  This shape file has 24 features and 6 fields.

[Structure of SpatialLinesDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YOen.jpg)

I would like to coerce into a psp object to use in the SpatStat package.  I have studied the Handling shapefiles in the spatstat package" but am having no luck; likely due to non-comprehension (Im fairly new, teaching myself as I go).

This is the code the pdf offers:

```
out<-lapply(x@lines,function(z) {lapply(z@Lines,as.psp) })
dat<-x@data
for (i in seq(nrow(dat)))
+ out[[i]]<-sapply(out[[i]],"marks<-", value=dat[i, , drop=FALSE])
```

Could someone please walk me thru how I would apply this code to my spatiallinesdataframe to create a psp object with the fields of my sldf converted to marks in my psp?  In particular I trip up on z as its not defined anywhere.  what is function (z)  Also how to handle "marks<-".

I have successfully used

```
RL.PSP<-as(RouteLines,"psp")
```

However, this throws this error and doesn't coerce the fields.

"In as.psp.SpatialLinesDataFrame(from) : 5 columns of data frame discarded"
I need the fields to be coerced into marks, because once I use the pointsOnLines function I need to be able to link the points back to the line they came from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you:

1. Have a `SpatialLinesDataFrame` with associated data
2. Would like to convert the coordinates to a `spatstat` `psp` object
3. Would like to add the data back as marks

If that's the case, using `fylk` from `maptools` as an example:

```
library("maptools")
library("rgdal")
library("spatstat")

base_dir <- system.file("shapes", package = "maptools")
fylk <- readOGR(base_dir, "fylk-val")

is(fylk)
# "SpatialLinesDataFrame" "SpatialLines"          "Spatial"
```

Now it sounds like you want to keep one mark per field (i.e. each one of your 24 observations in your `SpatialLinesDataFrame`), rather than one mark per line segment? That being the case we need to iterate over each connected curve (i.e. each of the 24 observations) and treat each one as an individual `psp` object:

```
out <- lapply(fylk@lines, function(i) { lapply(i@Lines, as.psp) })
out
```

Notice this is almost the same code you posted from the vignette. The outer `lapply` loop iterates over the `@lines` slot in `fylk`. The inner `lapply` loop takes each of these 24 in turn and iterates over it's internal `@Lines` slot and converts this to a `psp` object. My guess is you have one file with 24 fields (`@lines`/outer loop), and each one of the 24 fields will have 3 or more lines making up a closed polygon describing that field (`@Lines`/inner loop).

To add the data back in (stored as the `@data` slot) this is the second part of the example:

```
dat <- fylk@data
for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(dat))) {
  out[[i]] <- lapply(out[[i]], "marks<-", value = dat[i, , drop = FALSE])
}
```

This:

1. takes the data from `fylk` (stored in the `@data` slot) and saves it as `dat`
2. `dat` and `out` should have the same number of rows now (likely 24 in your data)
3. for each row of `out` this appends the relevant row from `dat` as `marks`

In your case replace `fylk` with your own data frame name.

Comment: Thank you Phil, following your coaching I was able to do exactly this with my data set!

Comment: I have just noticed however, that the marks are only added to the first of the 24 lists, but not the subsequent lists.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Aber_R It's because I made a mistake in the `for` loop. I used `seq_along(nrow(dat))` which just returns `1` instead of `seq_along(1:nrow(dat))`. I've fixed this above

Comment: Perfect.  Although I need to clarify - now that I have properly converted my lines into a list of list of psp objects, pointsOnLines fails (is.psp(X) is not TRUE).  IS there a final step in the conversion Im missing?  I did run ```out<-lapply(out,function(i){do.call("superimpose",i)})``` but the function still fails.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use `spatstat` classes `linnet`, `lpp` and `lppm` for your task at hand. For the conversion you can follow the help file for `as.linnet.SpatialLines` in `maptools`. I think it covers your case nicely:

```r
library(maptools)
#> Loading required package: sp
#> Checking rgeos availability: TRUE
library(spatstat)
#> Loading required package: spatstat.data
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> Loading required package: rpart
#> 
#> spatstat 1.61-0.036       (nickname: 'New improved formula') 
#> For an introduction to spatstat, type 'beginner'
dname <- system.file("shapes", package="maptools")
fname <- file.path(dname, "fylk-val.shp")
fylk <- readShapeSpatial(fname)
#> Warning: readShapeSpatial is deprecated; use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read
#> Warning: readShapeLines is deprecated; use rgdal::readOGR or sf::st_read
L <- as(fylk, "linnet")
print(max(vertexdegree(L)))
#> [1] 3
L0 <- as.linnet.SpatialLines(fylk, fuse=FALSE)
#> Warning: data contain duplicated points
print(max(vertexdegree(L0)))
#> [1] 2
## extract data associated with each network segment
head(marks(as.psp(L)))
#>     FNODE_ TNODE_ LPOLY_ RPOLY_    LENGTH VALINJE_ VALINJE_ID LTEMA VANNBR
#> 0        3      2      2      2  1429.487        1         97  3211     13
#> 1        5      4      2      1  7369.613        2         97  3211     13
#> 1.1      5      4      2      1  7369.613        2         97  3211     13
#> 1.2      5      4      2      1  7369.613        2         97  3211     13
#> 2        7      8      1      2 11040.943        3         64  3211     13
#> 2.1      7      8      1      2 11040.943        3         64  3211     13
#>         DATO LinesIndex LineIndex
#> 0   19970630          1         1
#> 1   19970630          2         1
#> 1.1 19970630          2         1
#> 1.2 19970630          2         1
#> 2   19970630          3         1
#> 2.1 19970630          3         1
```

Comment: Thanks - I am not sure using linnet would apply as my lines are not strait?

Comment: If you have SpatialLines then your lines are straight. So are psp objects. You won't find many R packages for curved lines...